# command object passing parameters into query crystal reports

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameters, crystal-reports, command

I've just decided I hate crystal reports...

I've got a query in a command which gives me the results of the history of VAT changes.

```
SELECT v1.StartDate,
isnull((
        SELECT TOP 1 v2.StartDate -1
        FROM [HISTVAT] AS v2
        WHERE v2.StartDate > v1.StartDate and v1.VATCode=v2.VATCode
        ORDER BY v2.StartDate asc
        ), '9999-12-31') AS EndDate,
v1.VATCode,
v1.Rate
FROM [HISTVAT] AS v1
```

Well, this comes up with this result:

```
+-----------+------------+---------+------+
| StartDate |   EndDate  | VATCode | Rate |
+-----------+------------+---------+------+
|2001-01-01 | 9999-12-31 |  VAT1   |  0%  | 
|2001-01-01 | 9999-12-31 |  VAT2   |  0%  |
|2008-12-01 | 2009-12-31 |  VAT3   | 20%  |
|2010-01-01 | 2011-01-03 |  VAT3   |17.5% |
|2011-01-04 | 9999-12-31 |  VAT3   | 20%  |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

I have changed the query to:

```
SELECT innerTable.*
FROM (
    SELECT v1.StartDate,
        isnull((
                SELECT TOP 1 v2.StartDate - 1
                FROM HISTVAT AS v2
                WHERE v2.StartDate > v1.StartDate
                    AND v1.VATCode = v2.VATCode
                ORDER BY v2.StartDate
                ), '9999-12-31') AS 'EndDate',
        v1.VATCode,
        v1.Rate
    FROM HISTVAT AS v1
    ) AS innerTable
INNER JOIN VAT T
    ON innerTable.VATCode = T.VATCode
INNER JOIN INVOICES s
    ON s.VATCode = T.VATCode
WHERE s.InvNo = 'SI150000004'
    AND s.InvDate BETWEEN innerTable.StartDate
        AND innerTable.EndDate
ORDER BY s.InvNo ASC
```

Now what I have to do is to pass the invoice number as a parameter which comes from the selection on the main report so my query uses the invoice number which selected the data to filter the query itself.

To do so I changed the:
    s.InvNo = 'SI150000004'
to
    s.InvNo = {InvN}

Which asked me to link to a column when saving and I did so to InvNo.

This is not showing the correct rates and duplicating every entry about 100 times - there's only 5 rows in the invoice lines and I'm getting over 200 pages.

The duplication issue I solved by suppressing rows which have the same description and net price.

My report is basicaly >  description, net price, vat, rate, gross price.

For an invoice created between 01.01.2010 and 03.01.2011 the rate should be 17.5% but I'm only getting 20% every time...

Does this make sense? I'm so confused....

Comment: First question is what is the purpose of changing the query? and secondly you shouldn't supress the if data duplicate is of `100 times` you need to check the query and crystal report design. Now why are you always depending on the query to get the desired results.. why don't you try to use crystal reports features to accomplish the task. Finally stop hating crystal reports and start understanding it, then you will achive your task

Comment: Hi Siva, well on my db I have a table which only holds the startdate of each VAT code and if one was changed it keeps the record replicating the entry with the same code but different startdate. My task is to given a document number I need to compare its date against the date range of the command. 

Now I got this to work (well, nearly) with correct values and no 100+ records duplicating. My problem is now implementing it to Sage X3 but I don't think anyone here can help with that :)

Thank you anyway

Comment: I am happy you were able to achive your crystal report task... Let me know if you need any more help with that.